# publisher not publishing on topic

Tags: ros, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

im trying to publish a message on a topic once but it never publishes the data at all. This is the code
in main

```
ros::init(argc, argv, "keeper_env");
   ros::NodeHandle n;
   ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise<std_msgs::Empty>("toggle_led", 1000);
   std_msgs::Empty msg;
   chatter_pub.publish(msg);
```

even putting it in a finite while loop dosent work

```
int i=0;
        ros::Rate rat(20);
    while(i<10)
    {   
        chatter_pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        i++;
                rat.sleep();
    }
```

but if i put it in an infitite loop then it publishes the data.

```
while(ros::ok())
    {   
        chatter_pub.publish(msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
        
    }
```

If i put it in a if condition in that infinite loop then it still dosent publish. i dont want it to be called infintely. i just need it once. can someone please help me

```
int i=0;
while(ros::ok())
    {   

        if(i==0)
        {   
            printf("Doses it go iun here \n");
            chatter_pub.publish(msg);
            i++;
        }
        }
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65774/publisher-not-publishing-on-topic/) by [vivek rk](https://answers.ros.org/users/5214/vivek-rk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2013-06-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Philip is right. The publisher need some time to connect to the subscribers. Your finite loop is just to short for that. I'm not sure what you expect from you condition case in the infinite loop as that is never true.

The proper solution to your problem is to use `pub.getNumSubscribers()` and wait until that is `> 0`. Then publish.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) on 2013-06-24**:
Ah, thanks for the hint about getNumSubscribers! I wasn't aware of that :-)

**Comment by [aschaefer](https://answers.ros.org/users/38195/aschaefer/) on 2018-12-05**:
In case you run into this issue with `rospy`: The corresponding function is called `get_num_connections()`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My first guess: you try to publish while the publisher is not fully set up. Can you try waiting for a second (e.g. using `usleep(1000*1000)`) between creating your publisher and sending the first message?

---

Originally posted by [Philip](https://answers.ros.org/users/4292/philip/) with karma: 990 on 2013-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5